# RPC connect to Umbrel

Tags: python

I have an Umbrel Node on my RaspberryPi4. It is connected to the same router as my Computer, but somehow I can't connect to it using python (bitcoinrpc).

My Code

```
rpc_user = "umbrel"
rpc_pass = "password"
rpc_host = "192.168.1.122"
rpc_port = "8332"
rpc_connection = f"http://{rpc_user}:{rpc_pass}@{rpc_host}:{rpc_port}"
print(rpc_connection)
rpc_client = AuthServiceProxy(rpc_connection, timeout=240)
```

This always results in the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/donbolli/code/python/bitcoin/crawler/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    rpc_client = AuthServiceProxy(rpc_connection, timeout=240)
  File "/media/donbolli/code/python/bitcoin/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitcoinrpc/authproxy.py", line 87, in __init__
    if self.__url.port is None:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/urllib/parse.py", line 185, in port
    raise ValueError(f"Port could not be cast to integer value as {port!r}")
ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as 'password'
```

What am I missing? What is done wrong?

Comment: Could it be a special char in the password is causing this issue, if so, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have some special character in either `rpc_user` or `rpc_pass` that makes the parser think that the host appears much earlier than it actually does. It's probably one of `:`, `@`, `;`, `?`, `#`, or `/`.

Comment: my password has such a chrachater in it, but how can i change the password?

Comment: I would try [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the value of `rpc_pass` when constructing the  `rpc_connection` URL. In other words change ":" to "%3A" and "@" to "%40" in the `rpc_pass` value.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Umbrel, so I cannot give instructions. But in general, you'll need to find the bitcoin.conf file that Umbrel's bitcoind is using and modify the password set in there, then restart bitcoind.